# How to run on BASH a python script that takes multiple arguments using GNU parallel?

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel, multiple-arguments

I have a python script which I normally execute from BASH shell like this:

```
pychimera $(which dockprep.py) -rec receptor1.pdb -lig ligand1.mol -cmethod gas -neut
```

As you see some of the arguments need an input (e.g. -rec) while others don't (e.g. -neut). I must execute this script 154 times with different inputs. How is it possible to run 8 threads in parallel using GNU parallel script?

```
pychimera $(which dockprep.py) -rec receptor1.pdb -lig ligand1.mol -cmethod gas -neut
pychimera $(which dockprep.py) -rec receptor2.pdb -lig ligand2.mol -cmethod gas -neut
pychimera $(which dockprep.py) -rec receptor3.pdb -lig ligand3.mol -cmethod gas -neut
...
```

Comment: You need to create a file with all commands in it. You can build that file automatically (and we can help with enough information to build that file). Then `module load parallel && parallel < commands.txt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example `commands.txt` generator script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
    echo "missing parameter: n"
    exit 1
fi

rm commands.txt 2> /dev/null 
dockp=$(which dockprep.py)

for((i=1;i<=$1;i++)); do
  echo "pychimera $dockp -rec receptor$i.pdb -lig ligand$i.mol -cmethod gas -neut" >> commands.txt
done
```

If you save above bash script as `cmdgen.sh` you can run it as:

```
bash cmdgen.sh 100
```

if you need `n` to be 100.

To run commands in parallel:

```
$ module load parallel
$ parallel < commands.txt
```

Comment: Yes, it works great! I can control the number of threads like this "parallel -j8 < commands.txt".

Answer (score 3):

I think you want this:

```
parallel 'pychimera $(which dockprep.py) -rec receptor{}.pdb -lig ligand{}.mol -cmethod gas -neut' ::: {1..154}
```

If you have other than 8 CPU cores, and specifically want 8 processes at a time, use:

```
parallel -j8 ...
```

If you want to see the commands that would be run without actually running anything, use:

```
parallel --dry-run ...
```

Comment: The --dry-run is very informative. But the input files do not necessarily follow the simplified format with indices that I used. They may vary completely.

Comment: The command I suggested works exactly the same as the answer you have accepted! I can only help you as well as your question describes your problem - if your problem is harder please alter your question and I, or maybe Ole (the author of **GNU Parallel**) will assist further.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I cannot help further: Your answer is literally character for character what I would have written.